# Passing parameter from the EJB to the SOAP Handler Resolver

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-ws

I can't pass parameter from application to handler.
In EJB I call my webservice:

```
MyNameWSService service = new MyNameWSService(URL); //MyNameWSService = class with annotation @WebServiceClient
((BindingProvider)service.getMyNameWSPort()).getRequestContext().put("login", login);
HeaderHandlerResolver handlerResolver = new HeaderHandlerResolver();
service.setHandlerResolver(handlerResolver);
service.getMyNameWSPort().callMyMethod();
```

In HeaderHandlerResolver i try read my parameter "login", but it's null:

```
import javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPHandler;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPMessageContext;

public class HeaderHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {
   public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext smc) {
     ...
     System.out.println(smc.get("login")); //it's null, why?
   }
...
```

}

I create HeaderHandlerResolver in order to add WS-Security Header to soap request and login/password may be different.

```
import javax.xml.ws.handler.Handler;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.HandlerResolver;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.PortInfo;

public class HeaderHandlerResolver implements HandlerResolver {

public List<Handler> getHandlerChain(PortInfo portInfo) {
      List<Handler> handlerChain = new ArrayList<Handler>();
      HeaderHandler hh = new HeaderHandler();
      handlerChain.add(hh);
      return handlerChain;
   }
}
```

Comment: Does your `HeaderHandlerResolver` implement both [javax.xml.ws.handler.HandlerResolver](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/handler/HandlerResolver.html) and [javax.xml.ws.handler.Handler< SOAPMessageContext >](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/handler/Handler.html)? Perhaps you could show more of your implementation...

Comment: code of HeaderHandlerResolver is added to post

Comment: How do you know that `login` is not null when you call `...getRequestContext().put("login", login)`?

Comment: value of login parameter is not null.

Comment: That does not answer the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not working for you because each time that you call `service.getMyNameWSPort()` you get a new proxy.

You are calling it twice:

1. Once to set the request context value
2. And again to invoke the web service

The second proxy that you're using to invoke the web service has not had it's request context updated with your `login` object.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, thank's, I rewrite my code and it's start to work:

```
MyNameWSService service = new MyNameWSService(URL); //MyNameWSService = class with annotation @WebServiceClient
MyNameWSPort servicePort = service.getMyNameWSPort()
((BindingProvider)servicePort).getRequestContext().put("login", login);

HeaderHandlerResolver handlerResolver = new HeaderHandlerResolver();
service.setHandlerResolver(handlerResolver);
servicePort.callMyMethod();
```